# Dynamic Objects in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, oop, object, for-loop

I have a scenario to create *dynamic objects* and also their variables by just entering the number of *objects* in *for loop* and the desired output is to *initialize* the variable name and *assignment* to corresponding array of *position vector*, in *Matlab*.
However I tried *`eval()`* but it doesn't help me as i want to write a function and other complexities, I teried very much but could find the proper solution of my scenario.
*What suggestions should according to my scenario, may be with function or without.*
Edit1: Position vector is predefined. String for number the object, its not compulsory.
**My Code:**

```
function myFunc(n)
for ii=1:n
Obj(ii) = 'some string required with its number of ii';
 Obj(ii).position=position(ii);
end
end
```

Comment: Please post a full example with a class definition. The given example doesnt really make sense. Why would a string have a position member? Where does the position vector come from? Why do you not return values from your function?

Comment: @Silas please check the edit1

Comment: It still doesnt make sense. How would you create a single object outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning your objects to a cell structure?

You can define a cell structure with two position indices, and the cell structure can hold other objects, e.g. fit objects, linear models

```
models = cell(100,100) 
for i = 1:100
    for j = 1:100
        Obj{i,j} = ....  % where ... is your expression that generates an object
    end
end
```

From inside the cell structure, you can open the object and inspect all the different types of variables, e.g. tables, doubles, formulas, cells, str, chararray etc.