# Iterate names for LinearModel fit Objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to iterate through a large number of LinearModel fit Objects and have them stored in a logical way, preferably through an indexing method, e.g. `model{x,y}`. Less preferable is `eval()`, which I have tried and in any case is not working. I get the error `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` - although the string expression works just fine outside of eval.

```
counter = 48;
str=strcat('model',+num2str(counter)); % Dynamic variable name
str1 = strcat(str,'=fitlm(tbl,modelspec)'); % Full string to be evaluated
eval(str1)
```

Ideally I wanted to do, while iterating through x

```
model{x,y} = fitlm(tbl,modelspec)  % This is the equivalent expression
```

But the error I get is

```
"Assignment using {} is not allowed for a FitObject."
```

I think this is similar to this question - with no answer:
[Dynamic Objects in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253794/dynamic-objects-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by assigning to a cell structure.
e.g.

```
model = cell(3,3) % Pre-assign a cell structure
for x=1:3
    for y=1:3
        model{x,y} = fitlm(tbl,modelspec);
    end
end
```